# Почему оператор присвоения не копирует объект?

Tags: c++, ссылки, перегрузка-операторов

Почему при первом выполнении строки `z = *this`, `z.val` копирует значение `this->val`
Но при втором `z.val` становится равна `0`.
В результате `b.val = 6`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class integer2
{
private:
    int val;
public: 
    integer2(int v0)
    {
        val = v0;
    }
    integer2& operator+(int s)
    {
        integer2 z(0);
        z = *this;
        z.val = z.val + s;
        return z;
    }

    int getVal()
    {
        return val;
    }
 };

int main()
{
    integer2 a(5), b(0);
    b = a + 5 + 6;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: operator+ возвращает ссылку на локальную переменную, а это UB.

Comment: Я тоже это заметил. Но это вузовская задача. Я подумал, может просто не знаю какой-то особенности работы С++.

Кстати, а разве объект z не должен удаляться после выхода из operator+?

Comment: то что задача вузовская не отменяет правил c++. Локальный объект уничтожается при завершении функции, именно поэтому возвращать ссылку нельзя, так как она ссылается на уже несуществующий объект. Сделайте возврат по значению.

Comment: Там висит код, и нужно сказать, чему будет равно b.val. В ответе - 6. Тесты показывают тоже самое. Такие дела. 
Локальный объект, видимо, не сразу удаляется, раз есть возможность получить 6 в b.val. 

В любом случае, код кривой, и пытаться понять его нет смысла. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ rikimaru2013 объясняет, почему так делать нельзя, я же попытаюсь объяснить что вообще произошло.

Первый оператор `+` отрабатывает условно-нормально - есть UB, но результат соответствует ожиданиям. Но он вернул ссылку на переменную, которой больше нет, и тот факт, что там до сих пор находится 10 - это заслуга исключительно современных ОС, где никакие прерывания не "портят" пользовательский стек. Кстати, если процесс получит в этот момент сигнал - значение "10" наверняка затрется.

Теперь выполняется оператор `+` второй раз. Вызывается он условно так:

```
temp1.operator + (6)
```

где `temp1` - это ссылка на уничтоженную локальную переменную `z`. Посмотрим выполнение построчно:

```
    integer2 z(0);
    z = *this;
    z.val = z.val + s;
    return z;
```

Первая строка создает новую переменную `z`, проинициализировав ее нулем. Но где она создается? Она создается на том же самом месте, что и прошлая переменная `z`, а значит, **`this` сейчас указывает на локальную переменную `z`**! Поэтому значение 10 в первой строчке затирается нулем.

Во второй строчке этот ноль присваивается самому себе, в третьей - к нему добавляется 6, и в четвертой строчке ссылка на локальную переменную опять возвращается.

В итоге в `b` обычно попадает 6.

Comment: Думаю, это заслуга не только ОС, но и выключенного/слабого оптимизатора.

Comment: *закрыл глаза, что обсуждаем поведение после UB по стандарту* - а почему (с) "Но где она создается? Она создается на том же самом месте, что и прошлая переменная z" - разве на стек не положится адресс возврата? Или оптимизация и всё inline

Comment: @rikimaru2013 фокус в том, что одна и та же функция вызывается два раза подряд. Разумеется, одна и та же локальная переменная попадет в одно и то же место.

Comment: @VladD, а чем Вам оптимизатор не угодил в этом случае?

Comment: @ixSci: Оптимизатор имеет право заинлайнить один из вызовов. Или переместить переменную из стека в регистр. А видя UB, он вообще имеет право делать что угодно.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересно было почитать.

Comment: @VladD, там идёт возврат ссылки, нельзя переменную поместить в регистр. Кроме того, если я не ошибаюсь, то компиляторы не видят UB, поэтому и реагировать на него не могут.

Comment: @ixSci: С другой стороны, это локальная переменная, так что её можно положить в регистр. Каким из правил воспользуется компилятор — предсказать невозможно. В этом и смысл UB.

Comment: @ixSci: Насколько я понимаю, компиляторы активно ищут UB, видят его и пользуются им: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ссылку! Как-нибудь доберусь, почитаю

Comment: @ixSci: Там достаточно длинное чтение. Я добавил ещё одну.

Answer (score 3):

Локальные переменные, созданные на стеке, уничтожаются при выходе из области видимости (в данном случае это выход из метода).

Таким образом, возвращая `integer2&` вы указываете на объект `integer2 z( 0 );`, которого уже не существует - это UB.

> В соответствии со стандартами C и C++, если выполнение программы приводит к переполнению знаковой целой переменной, или к любому из сотен других «неопределённых действий» (undefined behaviour, UB), то результат выполнения программы может быть любым: она может запостить на Твиттер непристойности, может отформатировать вам диск…
>   (с) хабра-пост

Правильный оператор+ в вашем случаи:

```
integer2 operator+( const int num )
{
    integer2 temp( *this );
    temp.val += num;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Бинарный operator+ концептуально возвращает **новое** значение, а не модифицирует this.

Comment: @alexolut я вам больше скажу: перегруженно вне класса и возвращает новое значение принимая тот же тип. Но тут ТС хочет вафельку и он получит вафельку.

Comment: Как я писал выше, это ВУЗовская задача. Я тоже посчитал код некорректным, но предположил, что возможно не знаю каких-то особенностей С++. Всё, что вы написали - я знаю, поэтому всё хорошо.

Comment: Кажется, это `+=`

Comment: @Qwertiy, а что не так?

Comment: Опасный код побеждён!

Comment: @rikimaru2013: О, отлично. Спасибо!

Comment: Я бы написал еще проще - `return integer2(val + num)` или даже `return val + num`.

Comment: @KAB, уже исправили.